# Identify bearing dimensions from its bearing number

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, bearings

In motors/pumps generally following bearings are used (ref: https://www.nke.at/en/bearings-applications/applications/electrical-motors):

1. Deep groove ball bearings
2. Cylindrical roller bearings
3. Angular contact ball bearings

All these bearings are designated with bearing number for example: Deep groove ball bearings: 6205.

Form this bearing no. we can easily have the information about its outer dimensions as given here:https://www.skf.com/in/products/rolling-bearings/ball-bearings/deep-groove-ball-bearings/productid-6205 OR from its catalogue.

Based on these outer dimensions, is there any way out to calculate the following specifications/dimensions:

1. Pitch diameter
2. Ball diameter
3. Number of balls in the bearing
4. Contact angle of the balls

Can somebody please let me know how can we go about this ?

Comment: Calculate? Use a lookup table...

Comment: @SolarMike, could you please provide some reference/links for the lookup tables ? I tried finding but couldn't get any,

Answer (score 1):

The trade numbers typically give you the envelope dimensions (inner and outer diameters, thickness). Everything else is at the discretion of the manufacturer - pitch diameter, rolling element size, quantity and contact diameter. This is why for the same trade number bearing you might see several different manufacturers, all with different load ratings.